# Add names to a column that doesn't have a name already in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created a a stored procedure that returns a table that looks like this:

```
(No column name)  (No column name)
 2                4
```

The table has no name, but I'll call the procedure, "proc".

How would I change the name of the two columns that currently have no name, so basically:

```
ColA    AnotherColumn
---------------------
  2          4
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Or [`WITH RESULT SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#m-using-execute-to-redefine-a-single-result-set)  if you can't edit the stored proc

Comment: All table columns have names. What you're describing is query output. Yo did something with a column, like include in a function without giving it an alias. All you have to do if alter the procedure code and supply those columns with aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alias them. This happens in a few cases, but often with aggregate functions and sub-queries

```
select
   sum(someColumn) as NewColumnName
   ,(select top 1 something From somewhere) ThisColumn  --notice the AS is optional
from YourTable
```

Another method which isn't ANSI standard is using `=`

```
select
   NewColumnName = sum(someColumn)
  ,ThisColumn = (select top 1 something From somewhere)
from YourTable
```